# Homomorphism between $p$-chain groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the below paper,

[Persistent Homology: An Introduction and a New Text Representation for Natural Language Processing](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/pub/homology.pdf)

the author provides an visual example of the boundary of a $p$-chain as seen

[image]

> Definition: The boundary of a $p$-chain is the $+_{2}$ sum of the boundaries of its simplices. The boundary of a $p$-chain is a group homomorphism from the $p$-chain group $C_{p}$ to the $(p-1)$-chain group $C_{p-1}$.

From the visuals, $p = 2$ so the homomorphism map is from $C_{2}$ to $C_{1}$.

What are the elements in $C_{2}$ then? Well, the elements are $2$-chains, by definition of a $p$-chain group.

What is the boundary of a $2$-chain then? Well, the $2$-chain is a subset of $2$-simplices in a simplicial complex. In other words, the $2$-chain is a subset of convex hulls of (2 + 1) points - i.e., subset of triangles.

For each of the $2$ - simplex, the boundary is the set of (2 - 1) - simplices face - i.e., $1$ - simplex face or edges. So a boundary of a $2$ - simplex is the blue triangle on the left. Another boundary of a $2$ - simplex is the blue triangle to the right of it. These two triangles are elements in $C_{2}$.

The definition of a group homomorphism requires that a map from a group $G$ to a group $G'$ be onto an operation preserving.

Since the homomorphism map is onto $C_{1}$ or $1$-chain group,  note that a $1$-chain is a subset of $1$ - simplices. The boundary of a $1$-simplex is the set of $0$-simplices faces - i.e., point/ vertex. It appears that arriving at the blue square requires the $+_{2}$ sum of the boundaries of $1$-simplex which a $1$-chain is a subset of. 
I am unable to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The boundary of a triangle is three edges. You don't need to know anything about vertices at this point. This would only be needed if you wanted to compute the boundary of the boundary of the triangle (which as you will later learn is 0).

Comment: PS. The statement that the two blue triangles are elements of $C_2$ is wrong, they are elements of $C_1$, because they only consists of edges (1-simplices). Only the yellow triangles are elements of $C_2$.

Comment: And finally, yes, getting the blue square is the modulo 2 sum, because this is how the group operation on chains is defined in that paper. The algebraic notion of boundary coincides with the "common sense" notion of boundary in reasonable situations. And the "common sense" boundary of the yellow square is the blue square-boundary.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Can I request you provide an explicit explanation, as an answer, as to how the square is arrived at from the group of $p+1$-chain? I will accept the answer and give it an upvote.

Comment: Quote: 'And finally, yes, getting the blue square is the modulo 2 sum' - can you explain this? What does it mean by the taking of modulo 2 sum of boundaries? I have no readings done related to AT prior to reading this paper.

Comment: These questions about $p$-chains are not related to algebraic geometry. Please stop tagging them as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it is a bit hard without seeing any algebraic topology background. The paper is (out of necessity) very terse as well.

The boundary of a triangle is three edges. In general the boundary of a $p$-simplex is the sum of all of its $(p-1)$-dimensional faces.

The first question is what do I mean by "sum". After definition 15 the author briefly mentions that addition of chains is the modulo 2 addition. There are other options in algebraic topology, but this one is very simple so we stick to it. Note that in this case a chain can be thought of as a sum of simplices, or a set of simplices - it is the same because the sum is just determined by which simplices are there.

Now that we know what a sum is, and we know how to compute the boundary of a simplex, we can also compute the boundary of a chain (that is, of a sum of simplices). If the boundary is supposed to be a group homomorphism then the only thing we can do is

$$\partial(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)=\partial(\sigma_1)+\partial(\sigma_2).$$

In your case let us denote by $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ the two yellow triangles. Then $\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ is a chain consisting of two triangles (geometrically the square). Let us also denotes by $a,b,c,d$ the sides of that square (blue edges) and by $x$ the diagonal of the square (also blue). Then

$$\partial(\sigma_1)=a+b+x$$
$$\partial(\sigma_2)=c+d+x$$

so

$$\partial(square)=\partial(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)=\partial(\sigma_1)+\partial(\sigma_2) = a+b+x+c+d+x=a+b+c+d$$

because $2x=0$ by our convention. So the "algebraic" boundary of the square is the "geometric" boundary of the square.

Comment: This is good. It's actually manageable with my background in Algebra but the author does plenty of handwaving which is very uncomfortable, unfortuantely!

Answer (score 1):

The author is trying to illustrate how the boundary map works on an explicit example of a $2$-chain.

Our 2-chain is the square, which is made up of two 2-simplices, call them $T_1$ and $T_2$. These are the left and right yellow triangles. So our 2-chain is the formal sum $T_1+T_2$. We want to compute $\partial(T_1+T_2)$.

Let's call the edges of $T_1$ $e_1, e_2$, and $e_3$, and the edges of $T_2$ $e_3,e_4,e_5$ (so $e_3$ is the shared edge).

The fact that $\partial$ is a group homomorphism just means that $\partial(T_1+T_2) = \partial(T_1)+\partial(T_2)$. But $T_1$ and $T_2$ are simplices, so we can compute $\partial$ as the sum of their edges.

So 
\begin{align}
\partial(T_1+T_2) = \partial(T_1)+\partial(T_2) & = e_1 + e_2 + e_3 + e_3 + e_4 + e_5 \\\\ &= e_1+e_2+2e_3+e_4+e_5
\end{align}

By $+_2$ he means the mod 2 sum, which just means that if I get an even coefficient, I set it to 0, and if I get an odd coefficient, I set it to 1. So my final computation is that $\partial(T_1+T_2) = e_1+e_2+e_4+e_5$, which is the blue square on the right.

Comment: This is clear; not only is this clear but the algebraic formalism you used to describe is a great mental relief from the author's hand waving!